# R: Change Vector based on range conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, vector, range, conditional-statements

I would like to change the vector elements based on conditions.
For example: I have a vector `v<-c(-3,5,-1,7,8,1,10,11)` and I want to generate as a result the vector `(-1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1)`
the conditions are

```
if the element is <-1 then set -1
if the element is >1 then set 1
otherwise 0
```

I could achieve this by using a serie of `ifelse` statements:

```
 v<-c(-3,5,-1,7,8,1,10,11)
    res<-rep(0,8)
    res<-ifelse(v<1,-1,res)
    res<-ifelse(v>1,1,res)
```

i think however there should be a more elegant and compact way to do this.
any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: `x[x > 1] <- 1; x[x < -1] <- -1`. This is pretty RTFM stuff, I suggest you start here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sign(v) * (abs(v) > 1)
# [1] -1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v[v >= -1 & v <= 1] = 0
v = sign(v)
```